# Required field, not working on AJAX bootstrap modal form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, required

i learn a lot of cases in here with the same issue, but still cant fix my code. I been trying many ways but i cant make it work. So i need your help, and if this code could be better.

Here it is the modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <label>Nombre Cliente</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="nombre" class="form-control input" required>        
    <label>Tipo</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="tipo1" name="tipo1" required></select>   
    <label>Marca</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="marca1" name="marca1" required></select>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="agregardatos" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar Registro</button>
</div>
```

Here is the ajax function

```
$('#agregardatos').click(function(){
    tipo=$('#tipo1').val();
    marca=$('#marca1').val();
    nombre=$('#nombre').val();

    agregardatos(nombre,tipo,marca);
});

function agregardatos(nombre,tipo,marca){
    cadena="tipo=" + tipo +
        "&marca=" + marca +
        "&nombre=" + nombre;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"agregardatos.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('tablacabe2.php');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your input elements needs to be present in <FORM> tag for making required field work. Reference url: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_required.asp

Comment: Ok. Now its works, shows the advice, but it post the register anyway. i think its related to "on click" function, but i dont know exactly what i have to change.

Any ideas?

Comment: I solved with .unbind().submit(function(e) instead onclick. thank you !!!!